# Another interview question in Javascript: removing items from the middle of an array using just .push .pop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, evaluation

Ive got this question during an Evaluation exam, which i failed in the end, but i sort of got a second shot at it. This was one of the questions, and i just cant seem to fathom how to solve it. 
the only operators allowed to be used are: 
.length()   .push(x)    .pop()

=== !==

<   >

<=  >=

&&  ||

And the task is as follows: 
Write a function which trims multiple zero's sequences to a single zero digit. The return value is the updated array. You are not allowed to use another array, and you need to implement it with one pass over the array (usually implemented by one loop only). In other words, each element in the array should change its index only once during the program.

```
var w = [1,2,0,0,0,0,5,7,-6,0,8,0,0]; 
var n = zeroTrim(w); 
console.log(n);  //print [1,2,0,5,7,-6,0,8,0]
```

I would really appreciate any help in solving it. Especially in understanding how can you trim elements from the middle of an array, using only .pop and .push?

Answer (score -1):

`Pop` the element if `two zero's are adjacent` else increment `i`

```
# Python3 , Should be able to follow the procedure
w = [1,2,0,0,0,0,5,7,-6,0,8,0,0,0,5]
i=0
while i<len(w)-1:
    # if there are two adjacent element equal to zero, pop it
    if w[i]==w[i+1]==0:
        w.pop(i)
    else:
        i+=1
print(w) # output: [1, 2, 0, 5, 7, -6, 0, 8, 0, 5]
```